# SQL query for getting data for the last 6 months grouped by month?

Tags: sql, soql

I know a basic query to get some results for the last 6 months. Let's say like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM RANDOM_TABLE
WHERE Date_Column >= DATEADD(MONTH, -6, GETDATE())
```

But what if I'd like to get results grouped by month - each month looking back 6 months into the past?
The first three rows of a result could ideally look like this (count of IDs is random):

| Month_and_year | COUNT(ID) |
| --- | --- |
| January 2017 | 120 |
| February 2017 | 160 |
| March 2017 | 240 |

The last three rows:

| Month_and_year | COUNT(ID) |
| --- | --- |
| November 2021 | 80 |
| December 2021 | 350 |
| January 2021 | 260 |

Hope it's understandable.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: As the *sql tag* description suggests, please [TAG](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) your RDBMS

Comment: Yes, thank you for reminding me. It's SOQL.

Comment: You would use the appropriate date functions to extract and concatenate the month name and year, and group by the same expression

Comment: have you looked at `GROUP BY` clause? 
 `select month_year,count(ID) FROM RANDOM_TABLE
WHERE Date_Column >= DATEADD(MONTH, -6, GETDATE()) GROUP BY month_year`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:**
Over the hours I made a few corrections. Most notably I corrected the self join query to reflect my intentions and also added more details to better explain what is going on.

To my knowledge there are two ways about it (which are probably the same under the hood).

Also, please note that these solutions assume you have a month field already in place. If you have a date or timestamp field, you should take one extra preparation step.

[Addendum] To be more precise, I'd say that the ideal would be to have a date/timestamp field that is truncated/flattened to the first day of the month.

As an example,

| month | amount |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 | 50 |
| 2021-02-01 | 20 |
| 2021-03-01 | 10 |
| 2021-04-01 | 100 |
| 2021-05-01 | 20 |
| 2021-06-01 | 40 |
| 2021-07-01 | 80 |
| 2021-08-01 | 50 |

The first is to use a "self-non-equi join"

```
SELECT
    a.month,
    SUM(b.amount) AS amount_over_6_months
FROM table AS a
    INNER JOIN table AS b ON a.month BETWEEN b.month AND DATEADD(MONTH, 5, b.month)
WHERE a.month >= DATEADD(MONTH, -5, GETDATE())
GROUP BY a.month
```

What happens here is that you are joining the table with itself. Specifically, for each row in the (a) alias, you will join six rows from the (b) alias. For each row you will join the rows where the month is equal, all the way back to five months prior. So...

| a.month | b.month | a.amount | b.amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 | 2021-01-01 | 50 | 50 |
| 2021-02-01 | 2021-01-01 | 20 | 50 |
| 2021-02-01 | 2021-02-01 | 20 | 20 |
| 2021-03-01 | 2021-01-01 | 10 | 50 |
| 2021-03-01 | 2021-02-01 | 10 | 20 |
| 2021-03-01 | 2021-03-01 | 10 | 10 |
| 2021-04-01 | 2021-01-01 | 100 | 50 |
| 2021-04-01 | 2021-02-01 | 100 | 20 |
| 2021-04-01 | 2021-03-01 | 100 | 10 |
| 2021-04-01 | 2021-04-01 | 100 | 100 |
| 2021-05-01 | 2021-01-01 | 20 | 50 |
| 2021-05-01 | 2021-02-01 | 20 | 20 |
| 2021-05-01 | 2021-03-01 | 20 | 10 |
| 2021-05-01 | 2021-04-01 | 20 | 100 |
| 2021-05-01 | 2021-05-01 | 20 | 20 |
| 2021-06-01 | 2021-01-01 | 40 | 50 |
| 2021-06-01 | 2021-02-01 | 40 | 20 |
| 2021-06-01 | 2021-03-01 | 40 | 10 |
| 2021-06-01 | 2021-04-01 | 40 | 100 |
| 2021-06-01 | 2021-05-01 | 40 | 20 |
| 2021-06-01 | 2021-06-01 | 40 | 40 |
| 2021-07-01 | 2021-02-01 | 80 | 20 |
| 2021-07-01 | 2021-03-01 | 80 | 10 |
| 2021-07-01 | 2021-04-01 | 80 | 100 |
| 2021-07-01 | 2021-05-01 | 80 | 20 |
| 2021-07-01 | 2021-06-01 | 80 | 40 |
| 2021-07-01 | 2021-07-01 | 80 | 80 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

Then it's just a matter of grouping based on the month in the (a) alias, and summing the amounts coming from the (b) alias.

The advantage of this approach is that it should be vendor and generation agnostic, save the `DATEADD()` fucuntion.

The second solution would be to use window functions. I cannot comment on whether this would work with your vendor and the specific version.

```
SELECT 
    month,
    SUM(amount) OVER (ORDER BY month ROWS BETWEEN 5 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
FROM table
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I will check it soon. I was superbusy doing something else. I've only tried the second solution and it works like a charm... Well, to be honest, I had to make it more complex as I probably didn't formulate my issue properly - I can't calculate sums right away from my data, I had to use a subquery first - but the principle with PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROWS is clear to me and works even in SOQL! Because of this I mark the solution as correct. But I haven't checked the first one yet. I will do it though.